# Strongly correlated? Terminology question

Tags: pr.probability, terminology

Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are jointly distributed real-valued random variables and for all outcomes $\omega_1$, $\omega_2$, we have
$$
X(\omega_1)\le X(\omega_2)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad Y(\omega_1)\le Y(\omega_2).
$$

**Edit**: As Louigi Addario-Berry's answer below shows, it may be better to consider the following variation: 
$$
X(\omega_1)< X(\omega_2)\quad\Longrightarrow\quad Y(\omega_1)\le Y(\omega_2).
$$

> Does this property have a name?

Comment: Isn't it the case that $X$ and $Y$ are monotonic functions of $X+Y$?

Comment: @James Martin: I think you're right, I'll update the question...

Comment: now my comment looks like a bit of a non-sequitur :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is along the lines of Tom's answer. $X$ induces a partial order on $\Omega$. In fact, it induces a total order on a partition of $\Omega$ into sets $X^{-1}(x)$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$); 
simply say $X^{-1}(x) < X^{-1}(y)$ if $x < y$.

By your property, there is then some non-decreasing function $y:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ such that for $x \in \mathbb{R}$, if $\omega_1, \omega_2 \in X^{-1}(x)$ then $Y(\omega_1)=Y(\omega_2)=y(x)$.

But then we can write $Y(\omega)=y(X(\omega))$. In other words, $Y$ is just a non-decreasing (measurable) function of $X$.

Comment: But $Y$ is not in general determined by $X$.  Simplest case:
`$$
\Omega = \{ (0,0), (0,1), (1,0), (1,1)\}.
$$`
$$
X(i,j) = i
$$
$$
Y(i,j) = 10i + j
$$
If $X=0$ then $Y$ may be either 0 or 1; if $X=1$ then $Y$ may be either 10 or 11.  A larger $X$ value entails a larger $Y$ value.  But $X$ does not determine $Y$.

Comment: Correct.  A STRICTLY bigger X entails a strictly bigger Y.  I was hasty.

Comment: So.... It seems that the answer given was correct, but maybe only shows why a different question should have been asked.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose that $\Omega$ is partially ordered.  If $$\omega_1 \le \omega_2 \qquad \mathrm{implies} \qquad X(\omega_1) \le X(\omega_2),$$ we say that $X$ is an *increasing random variable*.

This comes up naturally in percolation theory.  In this setting, $\Omega = \{0,1\}^{\mathbb Z^2},$ where $\omega(z) = 0$ if a site $z$ is *closed*, and $\omega(z) = 1$ if it is *open*.  See, for example, the beginning of Chapter 2 of Grimmett's *Percolation*.

Your property is useful in settings where $\Omega$ doesn't have a natural ordering, but one may wish to impose an ordering using some random variable $X$.  I would say that *$Y$ is increasing relative to $X$*, though I don't know a standard terminology.